# Firebase Storage store profile image from Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to get a Facebook profile picture and store it in Firebase Storage.
What I am doing is as follows;

1. get url of the profile picture (looks fine).
2. change to uri from url (I think it is also fine).
3. upload the file to Firebase Storage but 'uploadFile' method.

But I've got an error. This is my uploadFile.

```
private void uploadFile(Uri pUri) {
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    mStorageReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://project-66993355093102411.appspot.com/");
    mStorageReferenceImages = mStorageReference.child("Images/profile.jpg");
    //showHorizontalProgressDialog("Uploading", "Please wait...");
    StorageReference uploadStorageReference = mStorageReference.child(pUri.getLastPathSegment());
    //final UploadTask uploadTask = uploadStorageReference.putFile(pUri);
    final UploadTask uploadTask = mStorageReferenceImages.putFile(pUri);
    Log.d(TAG, "FacebookProfile:pUri: " + pUri);

    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot pTaskSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "uploadFileonSuccess:" + pTaskSnapshot);
            Uri downloadUrl = pTaskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            //hideProgressDialog();
            if (downloadUrl != null) {
                imageUploaded = true;
                //btnDownload.setEnabled(true);
                //Glide.with(context).load(downloadUrl).into(imageView);
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception pE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "uploadFileonFailure:" + pE);
        }
    }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot pTaskSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "uploadFileonProgress:" + pTaskSnapshot);

            //int progress = (int) (100 * (float) pTaskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / pTaskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
            //updateProgress(progress);
        }
    });
}
```

This is an error I've got.

> 07-21 02:31:42.441 25140-25140/com.mai.aso.masaya.teachu E/UploadTask: could not locate file for uploading:https://(link to profile picture)
>
> 07-21 02:31:42.442 25140-25140/com.mai.aso.masaya.teachu E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
>   An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.                                                      Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
>
> 07-21 02:31:42.443 25140-25140/com.mai.aso.masaya.teachu E/StorageException: No content provider: https://(link to profile picture)

I am a new android developer, and don't know what is going wrong.
I really hope you are willing to help me.
Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify what `pUri` is? Is that an `https://` URL to a Facebook profile photo? Why not just store that URL somewhere (like the Firebase Realtime Database) and share it, rather than re-upload the photo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when trying to upload facebook Uri to Firebase Storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324764/error-when-trying-to-upload-facebook-uri-to-firebase-storage)