# Error when trying to upload facebook Uri to Firebase Storage

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, firebase, firebase-storage

When users log in with Facebook (the only way to log in currently), and want to post something, I run some code to upload their profile picture first, so other users can see who the original poster is. It seems like I can get the user's profile picture Uri which is for example (taken from debug mode):
https://graph.facebook.com/(FACEBOOKID)/picture?height=200&width=200&migration_overrides=%7Boctober_2012%3Atrue%7D

However, when I run:

```
StorageReference posterPicture = mStorage.child("UsersPictures").child(profile.facebookID);
        posterPicture.putFile(profile.profilePictureURI).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {...});
```

It throws an error saying "no content provider"

> W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://graph.facebook.com/(FACEBOOKID)/picture?height=200&width=200&migration_overrides=%7Boctober_2012%3Atrue%7D
>
> Error Code: -13000,
>
> HTTP Response Code: 0

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that the URI has to be a file on your file system (you have to download it and re-upload it), or you need a content resolver that can handle `HTTPS` scheme'ed files.

That said, my question to you is: why? The file is already hosted on Facebook and easily retrievable by that URL, so why upload it again? You can very easily store and share that URL in the Firebase Realtime Database, no need to pay to host in in Firebase Storage.

Comment: I just realized that facebook as the graph api where you could get the user's profile picture if you have their facebook ID. It works now, thank you so much!